# How do I escape html in the "innerHtml" property with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a combo of javascript and my jsp that is adding some text and escaping it.  I also have some javascrpt that will allow me to edit the text after it has been submitted.  However the html renders when Click the edit button.

```
    function editCommentToggle( id )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+id);
    //user = theRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    //date = theRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
 -->   com = theRow.cells[2].innerHTML;


    idx = 2;
    maxlength = 250;

                // Comment field
        cell = theRow.cells[idx];
        while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);
        element = document.createElement("textarea");
        element.id="comments-"+id;
        element.rows="3";
        element.value = com;
        element.style.width = "400px";
        element.maxLength = "250";
        element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit(undefined, maxlength, this);}; 
        cell.appendChild(element);
```

**"theRow.cells[2].innerHTML;"** is grabbing the text or html in that cell, but if say there is a 'newline' it displays a`<br>`.....how should I structure this to preserve the escaped html??

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use textContent (or innerText in IE)

```
com = theRow.cells[2].textContent || theRow.cells[2].innerText
```

Comment: thanx friend...let me try that

Answer (score 0):

I had an old web application, no jQuery or other fancy libraries available. I tried if-then-else textContent/innerText fix but some reason did not work for dynamically created DIV element. So had to implement this alternative fix. Tested on Firefox, IE8, IE9 and Opera.

```
// XMLEscape reserverd characters
function XMLEscape(sValue, bUseApos) {
  var sval="";
  for(var idx=0; idx < sValue.length; idx++) {
    var c = sValue.charAt(idx);
    if      (c == '<') sval += "&lt;";
    else if (c == '>') sval += "&gt;";
    else if (c == '&') sval += "&amp;";
    else if (c == '"') sval += "&quot;";
    else if (c == '\'') sval += (bUseApos ? "&apos;" : "&#39;");
    else sval += c;
  }
  return sval;
}

var sprite = document.createElement("DIV");
sprite.setAttribute("class", "sprite_red");
sprite.setAttribute("style", "top:" + nextOffsetTop +"px");
sprite.innerHTML = XMLEscape(items[idx]);
scene.append(sprite);
```